# non-linear differentiation equation solution for $y'=\frac1{x+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=\frac1{x+y^2}$$
I'm struggling to find out the answer for this non-linear differentiation equation.
So far I learned only Bernoulli & Ricatti equation for solution of first order non-linear equation but none of which matches the formation of this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Swap the dependency of $y$ on $x$ with $x$ on $y$, i.e. write$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=\frac1{x+y(x)^2}\implies\frac1{\frac{dy}{dx}}=\frac{dx(y)}{dy}=x(y)+y^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to solve it by flipping  dependency (which is simpler in this case), you could always use the good old fashioned and trusted method of exactness. This should be one of the very first method to try if the other obvious choices fail.

There are many known ways to finding integrating factors. Below is one that worked.

Write the ode as

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx}  & =\frac{1}{x+y^{2}}\\
-dx+\left(  x+y^{2}\right)  dy  & =0\\
Mdx+Ndy  & =0
\end{align*}

Where $M=-1,N=x+y^{2}$. Since $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=0$ and$\frac
{\partial N}{\partial x}=1$. $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\neq\frac{\partial
N}{\partial x}$ then not exact. Lets try to find integrating factor.

$$
B=\frac{1}{M}\left(  \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial
y}\right)  =-1\left(  1-0\right)  =-1
$$

Since $B$ does not depend on $x$ it can be used as integrating factor which is

$$
I=e^{\int Bdy}=e^{-y}
$$

The ode becomes

\begin{align*}
IMdx+INdy  & =0\\
-e^{-y}dx+e^{-y}\left(  x+y^{2}\right)  dy  & =0
\end{align*}

Now it is exact. Therefore

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}  & =-e^{-y}\tag{1}\\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}  & =e^{-y}\left(  x+y^{2}\right)  \tag{2}
\end{align}

Integrating (1) w.r.t. $x$ gives

\begin{align}
\int\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}dx  & =\int-e^{-y}dx\nonumber\\
\phi & =-xe^{-y}+f\left(  y\right)  \tag{3}
\end{align}

Taking derivative w.r.t. $y$

$$
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}=xe^{-y}+f^{\prime}\left(  y\right)
$$

But from (2) $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}=e^{-y}\left(  x+y^{2}\right)  $,
hence the above becomes

\begin{align*}
xe^{-y}+y^{2}e^{-y}  & =xe^{-y}+f^{\prime}\left(  y\right)  \\
y^{2}e^{-y}  & =f^{\prime}\left(  y\right)
\end{align*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
f\left(  y\right)    & =\int y^{2}e^{-y}dy\\
& =-\left(  y^{2}+2y+2\right)  e^{-y}+c_{1}
\end{align*}

Substituting in (3) gives

$$
\phi=-xe^{-y}-\left(  y^{2}+2y+2\right)  e^{-y}+c_{1}
$$

Since $\phi=c_{2}$ some constant, then merging the two constants, the above becomes

\begin{align*}
-xe^{-y}-\left(  y^{2}+2y+2\right)  e^{-y}  & =C\\
e^{-y}\left(  -x-y^{2}-2y-2\right)    & =C
\end{align*}

Which is implicit solution for $y\left(  x\right)  $.

Answer (score 1):

Flip dependency as suggested by @user170231 :
$$ x'(y) = x + y^2.$$
Apply an integrating factor:
$$ \frac{d}{dy} e^{-y} x = y^2 e^{-y}.$$
Integrate:
$$ x e^{-y}  = -e^{-y} (2 + 2 y + y^2) +C.$$
Now you have an implicit solution. If you give me an $x$, I find a root numerically and give you a $y$.